# What is Powershell (dotnet global)

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, installation, module

I was leaning a powershell tutorial where the following code was written:

```
dotnet tool install --global PowerShell
```

I tried the code — and found that it installed a something named `Powershell(dotnet global)`

My question is it is another version of powershell or module or tool or what?
And another question is that without this Powershell(dotnet global) – Will I not be able to install any module?

*I am using Windows Terminal and that thing shows like the below picture*
[image: reference for powershell(dotnet global)]

Answer (score 1):

You have installed PowerShell (formerly PowerShell core), the successor to Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/introducing-powershell-as-net-global-tool/

Hello , I have put this link that can help you to find the answer to your question.

Comment: I have seen it. But did not find the answer I want. Please actually answer the question.